# Print out symmetric matrix from compactly stored array

Tags: c, matrix

I have an array of the form (3x3 case as an example)

$$A = [a_{11}, a_{12}, a_{22}, a_{13}, a_{23}, a_{33}] $$

corresponding to the symmetric matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\ a_{12} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\ a_{13} & a_{23} & a_{33} \end{pmatrix}$$

I want to print out this very matrix (in general of size NxN) given the array A (in general of length N*(N+1)/2) in a nice way.
My approach was

```
void print__symm_matrix_packed(double* arr, int N){
  
  int idx2 = 0;

  for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
    printf("(");
    
    int idx1 = i;
    
    for(int j=0; j<N; j++){ 
      if(j < i){
        printf("%f ", arr[idx2 + j]);  
      } else {
        printf("%f ", arr[idx1]);
      }
      idx1 += j+1;
    }
    idx2 += i+1;
    printf(")\n");
  }
}
```

Is there room for some elegant improvement?

Comment: I think you mean $$ A = [a_{11}, a_{12}, a_{13}, a_{21}, a_{22}, a_{23}, a_{31}, a_{32}, a_{33}] $$, Am I correct ?

Comment: @MiguelAvila No, it is stored column wise back to back

Answer (score 1):

I think it the following is a good approach:

```
//use lowercase on non constant values
void print_symmetric_packed_matrix(double* compact_matrix, int n)
{
    const int entries = N*N;
    for (int i = 0; i < entries;)
    {
        //i++ here avoids i != 0 each iteration
        printf("%f ", compact_matrix[i++]);
        if (i % N == 0) printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I hope it helped you.

Comment: Thank you, but this does not display the matrix that I mentioned in my question.